# How to secure the cloud hosted web server safe from attack ?

Tags: attack-prevention

We have got a web server (Apache)  hosted externally. It has got multiple times attacks from the hackers (The Index file getting changed) even after getting  moved from another location also.

Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance for all your suggestions.

With regards,
Sahu

Comment: There isn't enough information here to provide useful answers.

Comment: Check your server and website for vulnerabilities. You have the accesslogs. Also check for backdoors. And there are many free penetration testing tools like OWASP ZAP.

Answer (score 0):

Sahu,

As a baseline, please reference the [NIST Special Publication 800-44 Version 2](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-44-ver2/SP800-44v2.pdf) **Guidelines on Securing Public Web Servers**.

Also, take a look at this [post](http://www.slashroot.in/how-to-secure-apache-web-server) on securing Apache web servers.